# How to build a remote_to link and pass a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model: ThreadParticipation

I want to build a link that send the ThreadParticipation.id and a param hide == true.

How can I build a link that does this?

**ThreadParticipation Controller:**

```
def hide
  @record = ThreadParticipation.find(params[:id)
  @record.hide == params[:hide]
  @record.save
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= link_to "hide", '/thread/:id/thread_participations/:id/hide', :remote => true %>
```

Does that look right? How do I pass a param a long with the link_to (hide == true) ? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
<%= link_to "hide", "/thread/#{thread_id}/thread_participations/#{id}/hide?hide=true", :remote => true %>
```

Or better still, define a route to get the /thread/:thread_id/thread_participation/:id part. Lets say the route is hide_thead_pariticipation_thread_path

```
<%= link_to "hide", hide_thread_participation_path(thread_id,:hide => true), :remote => true %>
```

Also your controller code seems to be using "@record.hide == params[:hide]". Maybe its just a = there?